# How to build spider in Scrapy around the list of urls?

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the data from Reddit using spider. I want my spider to iterate over each url in my list of urls (which is in file named reddit.txt) and collect data but I receive an error where the whole list of urls is taken as started urls. Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
import time

class RedditSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'reddit'
    allowed_domains = ['www.reddit.com']
    custom_settings={ 'FEED_URI': "reddit_comments.csv", 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv'}
    with open('reddit.txt') as f:
        start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]

    def parse(self, response):
        for URL in response.css('html'):
            data = {}
            data['body'] = URL.css(r"div[style='--commentswrapper-gradient-color:#FFFFFF;max-height:unset'] p::text").extract()
            data['name'] = URL.css(r"div[style='--commentswrapper-gradient-color:#FFFFFF;max-height:unset'] a::text").extract()
            time.sleep(5)
            yield data
```

Here is my output:

```
scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported: Unsupported URL scheme '': no handler available for that scheme
2020-07-26 00:51:34 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET ['http://www.reddit.com/r/electricvehicles/comments/lb6a3/im_meeting_with_some_people_helping_to_bring_evs/',%20'http://www.reddit.com/r/electricvehicles/comments/1b4a3b/prospective_buyer_question_what_is_a_home/',%20'http://www.reddit.com/r/electricvehicles/comments/1f5dmm/any_rav4_ev_drivers_on_reddit/' ...
```

Part of my list:`['http://www.reddit.com/r/electricvehicles/comments/lb6a3/im_meeting_with_some_people_helping_to_bring_evs/', 'http://www.reddit.com/r/electricvehicles/comments/1b4a3b/prospective_buyer_question_what_is_a_home/', 'http://www.reddit.com/r/electricvehicles/comments/1f5dmm/any_rav4_ev_drivers_on_reddit/', 'http://www.reddit.com/r/electricvehicles/comments/1fap6p/any_good_subreddits_for_ev_conversions/', 'http://www.reddit.com/r/electricvehicles/comments/1h9o9t/buying_a_motor_for_an_ev/', 'http://www.reddit.com/r/electricvehicles/comments/1iwbp7/is_there_any_law_governing_whether_a_parking/', 'http://www.reddit.com/r/electricvehicles/comments/1j0bkv/electric_engine_regenerative_braking/',...]`

Will appreciate any help with my issue. Thank you!

Comment: Where are you requesting the URLs?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm kinda of newb with spacy.  I want to request the URLs from the list reddit.txt, may be I'm wrong with the code how to input my list..

Comment: With problems like this you need to include the error you are having in your question. Also, having a sample of `reddit.txt` would help.

Comment: I've updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can open the url file in the  `start_requests` method and add a callback to your `parse` method.

```
class RedditSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "reddit"
    allowed_domains = ['www.reddit.com']
    custom_settings = {'FEED_URI': "reddit_comments.csv", 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv'}

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('reddit.txt') as f:
            for url in f.readlines():
                url = url.strip()
                # We need to check this has the http prefix or we get a Missing scheme error
                if not url.startswith('http://') and not url.startswith('https://'):
                    url = 'https://' + url
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for URL in response.css('html'):
            data = {}
            data['body'] = URL.css(
                r"div[style='--commentswrapper-gradient-color:#FFFFFF;max-height:unset'] p::text").extract()
            data['name'] = URL.css(
                r"div[style='--commentswrapper-gradient-color:#FFFFFF;max-height:unset'] a::text").extract()
            time.sleep(5)
            yield data
```

Make sure the contents of your input file are correctly formatted and have one url per line:

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/electricvehicles/comments/lb6a3/im_meeting_with_some_people_helping_to_bring_evs/
http://www.reddit.com/r/electricvehicles/comments/1b4a3b/prospective_buyer_question_what_is_a_home/
http://www.reddit.com/r/electricvehicles/comments/1f5dmm/any_rav4_ev_drivers_on_reddit/
```

Comment: Same thing, receive this type of error: Error downloading <GET ['http://www.reddit.com/r/electricvehicles/comments/lb6a3/im_meeting_with_some_people_helping_to_bring_evs/',%20'http://www.reddit.com/r/electricvehicles/comments/1b4a3b/prospective_buyer_question_what_is_a_home/',%20'http://www.reddit.com/r/electricvehicles/comments/1f5dmm/any_rav4_ev_drivers_on_reddit/'....

Comment: I believe you have an issue with getting the individual urls.
I've updated the code above and it is crawling correctly. However your css selector isn't working and will need to be updated

Comment: yes, the css selector could be wrong, but the problem is that I cannot even run the spider. I'm using your code and again the whole list of urls runs as well as this error appears: scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported: Unsupported URL scheme '': no handler available for that scheme

Comment: This is a different error due to the input of your txt file.
You have to make sure that each individual url starts with `http://` or `https://` and has no whitespace. I've added a check in the code to make sure it is using http/https

Comment: Also you have to make sure that you have one URL per line in your `txt` input file. If not you will get an error like the one in your input that you have added.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the Exception or your file reddit.txt I can't say for sure, but I believe your problem is in the txt file.

Try running this in a separated script: (Or add the `print()` in your spider)

```
with open('reddit.txt') as f:
    for url in f.readlines():
        print(url)
```

If I'm right, the output will be all the urls in a single string, instead of urls separated by lines.

Make sure you are breaking into new lines for each URL inside the txt file.